# Is it possible to view content of page renderer within xaml viewer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Forms as a primary framework, and I rely heavily on visual studio Xaml viewer. It came that I must use Page Renderers to get some native controls from Xamarin.iOS.

Is there anyway to display the native controls in Xaml viewer? What is the best way to design the native UI components within Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to display the native controls in Xaml viewer?

**Unfortunately** ,  native controls can not display in Xaml Viewer.

> What is the best way to design the native UI components within Xamarin?

If want to show native control in Viewer in IOS, [just using IOS designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/creating-ui-objects?tabs=windows#using-xamarin-ios-designer) may be the best way to see native viewer, however this is not total viewer in Xaml Viewer.You also can just see part view in Xaml,so this also has a little regret.